# componentDidUpdate prevProps gives me current / new props

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I'm trying to integrate a leaflet map but I think that is not the problem here. Anyway to re-render my map I want to use componentDidUpdate to see if the props changed I pass down to my map component from the parent components. BUT now comes the problem, whenever I try to `console.log(prevProps.xx, this.props.xx)` they are exactly the same, even though I just updated it, so I can't really use componentDidUpdate, is there any other way? Also componentWillReceiveProps won't work, the moment I update my state at the parent component and pass it down to my map component, it's just always 1:1 the same, so can't compare things.

here is my code:

```
var Map = React.createClass({

map: null,
tileLayer : null,

componentDidMount: function() {
   // code to run just after the component "mounts" / DOM elements are created
   // make the AJAX request for the GeoJSON data
   // create the Leaflet map object
   if (!this.map) this.init('mapid');
 },
 componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
   console.log(nextProps.labels, this.props.labels);
 },
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   const zoom = this.props.labels.zoom;
   const mapstyle = this.props.labels.mapstyle;
   const latlng = [this.props.labels.lat, this.props.labels.lng];
   this.map.setView(latlng);
   this.tileLayer.setUrl(mapstyle);
   console.log(prevProps.labels, this.props.labels);
  },

 init: function(id) {
  const zoom = this.props.labels.zoom;
  const mapstyle = this.props.labels.mapstyle;
  const latlng = [this.props.labels.lat, this.props.labels.lng];
  if (this.map) return;
  // this function creates the Leaflet map object and is called after the Map component mounts
  this.map = L.map(id).setView(latlng,zoom);


  // a TileLayer is used as the "basemap"
  this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer(mapstyle).addTo(this.map);

  // set our state to include the tile layer
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  },

  });
```

Comment: you are mutating the same object so it will always be the same, you should return a new object. Make a copy of your map variable and try again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Create a new state element, let's say `response`
2. Assign the props to `response`
3. Try writing the function inside `render()`